# Download Excel or other binary file with loader or progress meter using JQuery without using Cookies

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, fetch, filesaver.js

How do you show the user a "loading" widget or progress meter while downloading an Excel or other binary file using JQuery without using cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $.ajax(url, {
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: jqXHR.getResponseHeader('content-type')});
            var fileName = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('content-disposition').split('filename=')[1].split(';')[0];
            saveAs(blob, fileName);
        },
        progress: function(e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                const completedPercentage = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
                if (completedPercentage >= 100) {
                    $("#loader").dialog("close");
                }
            }
            else {
                if (console) {
                    console.log('Content length not reported. Fix this server side.');    
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The Fetch API seems to be a much better way to pull a binary file via ajax, but does not support IE which is a requirement for me. Here is the code I looked at in case it helps anyone. I didn't add the close "loader" logic, but I'm pretty sure you could do that right before or after saving the file.

```
    fetch(url, {
        responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => saveAs(blob, 'test.xlsx'));
```

This answer was pieced together from the web and several SO posts.  See below for relevant links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197970/1048376 (JQuery and downloading binary data via $.ajax())
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48437227/1048376 (JQuery and downloading binary data via $.ajax() - I used this solution)
- https://github.com/likerRr/jq-ajax-progress (Lightweight jQuery plugin that adds support of progress and uploadProgress promises to $.ajax() - I used this solution)
- http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/
  (you could use this instead of the plugin above)
- https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js (FileSaver plugin home - I used this solution)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25186103/1048376 (using FileSaver)
- https://github.com/axios/axios (just looked at this, didn't try to implement) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
  (better than JQuery but not IE compatible so not for me)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62173022/1048376 (how to get filename from header - I used this solution)
- http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/ (fileDownload plugin home page)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/1048376 (excellent post by John Culviner, the fileDownload plugin creator.  I have been using this plugin for years, but a Vericode scan is forcing me to use HttpOnly cookies across the board (sigh).)