# How to send csrf token in xmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, django, httpresponse, csrf-token

Using `Ajax` or `xmlHttpRequest` I want to download *excel* file from django backend. Backend creates file in memory and returns it to user.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134698/get-excel-file-xlsx-from-server-response-in-ajax/47197970#47197970) I should use for this xmlHttpRequest, but there is no info how to set *csrf middleware token* in `post request`.

**I tried:**

To set  `request.setRequestHeader` like this:
`request.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token, window.CSRF_TOKEN)` - **token is missing**

and in data:

```
request.send({'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN, 'req': 'ExportAllMessages'});
```

I can't find any working solution with Ajax.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

The location of CSRF token varies between projects. Just look at the template of your page and find how it is saved. Potential locations are:

- `<meta>` tag in `<head>`
- `<input>` field of `type="hidden"` in the form
- cookie
- global variable, which is not the case in your situation